# Weird behaviour on async catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await

Lately I keep encountering a problem which I cannot replicate, nor wrap my head around

```
try { 
  const result = await makeReq()
  console.log(result)
} catch (err) { 
  console.log(err)
}
```

This is a basic try catch. If makeReq throws an error, then it will be caught by the catch since  I am using the async await syntax.

BUT

there are some errors on makeReq() that I cannot catch with a basic try catch block. In stead I need to do something like this.

```
try { 
  const result = await makeReq().catch(err => console.log('my interesting err: ', err)
  console.log(result)
} catch (err) { 
  console.log(err)
}
```

I would like somebody, anybody to explain and to help me mock an example of this.
I believe that the ".catch" attached on the async/await call "makeReq" is for async errors thrown inside the call, but I have tried to replicate making a request, rejecting a new Promise in stead of an basic exception and it is still caught by the main "catch" in the "try/catch" block.

Unhandled Promise Rejection is what I get if I do not attach the .catch on the await call.

````makeReq``` is just a placeholder for some SAP api that I am using the created side effects (i.e. make a req/run a query - (cds.run - if anybody is interested))

Comment: Can you post `makeReq` definition?

Comment: what are these "some errors"?

Comment: Unhandled Promise Rejection is what I get if I do not attach the .catch on the await call.

Comment: ````makeReq```` is just a name for some SAP api to make a request. I tried to mock it in multiple ways. Returning a promise that is resolved after a timeout, rejected with another promise, throwing error inside it, no luck